# 5e-08 to decimal in PHP

Tags: php, bitcoin

I am trying to convert 5e-08 into a proper decimal point, how can i accomplish this with PHP

```
<?php

$value = 5;

$real_btc = $value/1e8;

echo $real_btc;
```

This returns

```
5.0E-8
```

I need it to return the proper decimal value of 0.00000005

How can i do this with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) with the appropriate format specifier:

```
printf("%.8f", 5 / 1e8);
```